# I need assistance with node.js scripts and how to run and etc

Tags: php, html, node.js

Basicly i am trying to run the node.js script with a cmd here is what i get error on

```html
var mysql = require('mysql');
var log4js = require('log4js');
var io = require('socket.io')(3000);
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
var md5 = require('md5');
var sha256 = require('sha256');
var math = require('mathjs');
var antiSpam = require('socket-anti-spam');
var seedrandom = require('seedrandom');
var crypto = require('crypto');
```

[here is a example of what kind of error i get (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTk9K.png)

and i dont understand much out of this so i appriciate all answers!

Comment: The errors are self-explanatory. You are missing mysql module. Install it first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`1`.**

This is a node file, to run the node file, you must have node installed

what you have done is just provided the `site.js`

If node is already installed then

do `npm install`

then `node site.js`

just do `console.log(process.argv)` inside `site.js` file, you will get

`[ '/home/pk/.nvm/versions/node/v7.6.0/bin/node',
  '/media/pk/E/test/site.js' ]`

The first index is the node command path, second is the path to your file

**`2`.**

`Error: cannot find module mysql`

means you don't have the mysql module installed

do `npm install mysql --save`, or if you want to install all the dependencies listed in your `package.json`, then just do `npm install`

you can do `npm install module_name --save` for the each required module

Comment: yeah, but what type of os do i need?

Comment: also i dont have a package.json in the bot folder

Answer (score 0):

Download nodejs from https://nodejs.org/en/.
Run it with `node site.js`

Answer (score 0):

Just create a package.json file containing the following json object:

```
{
  "name": "my-cool-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is my cool app",

  "author": "Me",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "mysql":"",
    "log4js":"",
    "socket.io":"",
    "request":"",
    "fs":"",
    "md5":"",
    "sha256":"",
    "mathjs":"",
    "socket-anti-spam":"",
    "seedrandom":"",
    "crypto":""
  }
}
```

Then run in the command prompt:

```
npm install
node site.js
```